# Storage configuration leads to Ubuntu Linux Server Boot failure - ( initramfs )

Tags: ubuntu, storage, lvm, boot, initramfs

Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation is **completed and successful** but the OS doesn't boot!
What does mean `initramfs` ?

I've tried to install **Ubuntu Server 22.04** on VM.
Installation is **completed and successful** but the OS doesn't boot!
I face this after rebooting the VM:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5d2V.png

This is my **storage configuration**:
(I have **two storages**. I have two config one of them as LVM and have to separate some directories as partitions, as you see here)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCI3e.png

> What's the problem !?

Comment: Most likely something strange happened during installation. As it's a new system, please just try a new install. Diagnosing such problems is often not worth the time.

Comment: If the problem persists, verify or recreate your installation medium. I once had this issue and recreating the USB drive fixed it.